# A problem with compare item value

Tags: .net, linq, dictionary

I have defined my class:

```
public class Host 
{
     public string Name;
}
```

then a strongly-typed dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Host> HostsTable;
```

then I try to compare a value:

```
 if (HostsTable.Values.Where(s => s.Name == "myhostname") != null) { doSomething }
```

and the problem is, nothing is found, even I'm sure the item is on the list. What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

`Where()` returns another `IEnumerable<Host>`, so your test for null is not checking that there is a matching item.

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
if(HostsTable.Values.Any(s => s.Name == "myhostname")) { doSomething }
```

`Any()` returns `true` if there are any items that match the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 if (HostsTable.Values.Any(s => s.Name == "myhostname")) { doSomething }
```

The [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb910023.aspx) operator filters a sequence based on a predicate.

The [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) operator determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

See the [standard linq operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb394939.aspx) document on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might also be in your string comparison:

```
if(HostsTable.Values.Any(s => s.Name.Equals("myhostname", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) { doSomething }
```